# Why won't this SVG's fonts render on Wikipedia?

Tags: svg, wikipedia

The following file has been uploaded several times with different fonts (e.g. `Serif` and `Liberation Serif`) in the ring. However, all resulted in the text missing. Currently, the workaround is to pre-render the fonts and upload it rasterized, but obviously this is not ideal.

At first I thought it might've been my drawing tool (Inkscape) not properly generating the XML, but I looked at it and the `font-family` attribute was properly set.

**So why isn't Wikipedia rendering this correctly?** Surely `font-family:Serif` is generic enough for its engine.

#### Intended render:

[image: The image in question, but rendered correctly]

#### Wikipedia's render:

[image: The image in question, but rendered without the fonts]

Comment: Since this is about server-side rendering of XML, I figure it belongs on this SE. If I'm wrong, please direct me to the proper one.

Comment: Is the problem only with the png renderer wikimedia uses?  [The first version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/3/37/20170914023516%21Alternate_History_Republic_of_Florida_Seal.svg) does render the text on my FF (not at correct scale, but it renders) And if so, [do you know which/have access to the] rastering tool wikimedia does use?

Comment: @Kaiido yes, only with the PNG that Wikipedia renders (you can see this in the file history section). Of course, when you ask it for the SVG, it's up to the browser so that works fine. I don't have their rastsrizor, no

Comment: One possible solution would be to embed the font directly in the file, though it will make it a lot heavier than what it is already, and I don't even know if the rasterizer would support it or not (since we don't know what it is...) You can try this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fli8q1ee9uy63qj/wiki.svg though you will probably need to adjust the text positions. An other (and probably better) solution would be to vectorize your texts from inkscape, you would loose the text abilities, but does it really matter for wikimedia?

Comment: Here is a version where the text has been vectorized. This should work with any rasterizer :https://www.dropbox.com/s/4b83scsfh1dyj3z/wiki_vect.svg?dl=0

Comment: Wikipedia rasterizes with rsvg. It's been eight years since I have been active in the WP grafics community, but at that time we would have urged any uploader to convert text content to plain path data in icons, logos and comparable content to ensure a faithfull representation. Help is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:SVG_help